# Attempting to return result in custom async method doesn't compile

Tags: asynchronous, task, .net-5

I've been trying to make a method that can be awaited, i.e. be async in .NET 5.

From what I know about asyncing this should work:

```
public Task<int> AsyncMethod()
{
    return 3;
}
```

Of course this is going to immediately return and there would be no point in awaiting it BUT the problem is that Visual Studio gives me an error on the "return" line and that error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'" which seems really odd because I thought this is exactly how you're supposed to do it.

If I change `return 3` to `return Task.FromResult(3)` then it works but I wonder why the first one doesn't work AND are the two things exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Task<int> AsyncMethod()
```

That says this method returns a value of type `Task<int>`. That doesn't match with your `return 3`, so that causes the error.

To make the conversion from `return 3` to `Task<int>` automatic, you need to change the method declaration to:

```
public async Task<int> AsyncMethod()
```

Comment: Huh... I thought the "async" keyword is only added is you need to use "await" in the method body?

Comment: Kind of.. `async` turns the method into a state machine. Then you can return values directly (the state machine deals with `Task`s). If you dont make it a state machine, you have you handle `Task` transformations yourself.

Comment: A-a-a-a-a-and, is making it `async` and `return 3` the same as NOT making it `async` and doing `return Task.FromResult(3)`?

Comment: Yes, those are two different things! You can see what the compiler converts these to using sharplap.io. Compare [`Task.FromResult`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMBWAblxQGZi1CBhQgb10PeNpQDYAeASwB2MAHyEAglACeggMYBZODAAWAewAmACgCUbDqxwcjxAOzFuAOgBiCVWABKcKAFcANjE3VtlQxwC+uH5AA) vs [async](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMBWAblxQGZi1CBhQgb10PeNpQA5iA2ADwBLAHYwAfIQCCUAJ4iAxgFk4MABYB7ACYAKAJRsOrHB1PEA7IWqUTHAL647QA). The `async` version gets converted into a state machine, surprisingly different from the code you write.